# Creating a simple meteorite package

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I just can't seem to get it loading. I want to add two files in my client but they don't show up no matter what.

Package.js:

```
Package.describe({
    summary: "Loads extjs 4.2.0 library"
});

Package.on_use(function (api){
    api.add_files('ext-all.js', 'client');
    api.add_files('ext-all.css', 'client');
});
```

The package is supposed to inject those to files. I've looked a dozen times at other packages and can't see why my files are not added to the page.

smart.json:

```
{
    "name": "mextjs",
    "description": "Loads extjs 4.2.0 library",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/ciokan/mextjs",
    "author": "Mihalcea Romeo",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "git": "https://github.com/ciokan/mextjs",
    "packages": {}
}
```

The package is on github and I load it in my project's `smart.json`:

```
"mextjs": {
    "git": "git@github.com:ciokan/mextjs.git"
},
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a local package?

Comment: updated my question with details.

Comment: I had issues doing something similar , hadnt run `mrt add mypackagename` .. Even though the files were in /packages and all looked good. Add a `console.log('stuff');` to the package.js and you should see it read .

Answer (score 0):

if you can bundle mextjs into a npm module you can load it into your packages by using :

```
Npm.depends({
    'mextjs':"0.1.0"
});
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't want a module which bundles another module. I just want to inject 2 files: one css and one js. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you export a global for your package in your `package.js`?

```
  if (api.export)
    api.export('MyGlobal');
```

[Here's](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/d3/package.js) an example from an official Meteor `package.js`.

The only other difference I see in my own custom packages is the manner in which the **project**-level `smart.json` references the repo:

```
"git": "https://github.com/myuser/mypackage"
```

Looks like your **package**-level reference uses this format.

Comment: As simple as it looks it doesn't work. I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything right. I've changed also the url in `smart.json` which was a long shot because meteor actually was downloading the package. It's just that the files are not injected in my client template.